# Command copied from the command line not running when called with subprocss.Popen in Python

Tags: python

Scratching my head... this curl command will work fine from the command line when I copy it from here and paste it in my Windows 7 command line, but I can't get it to execute in my Python 2.7.9 script. Says the system cannot find the specified file. Popen using 'ping' or something like that works just fine, so I'm sure this is a goober typo that I'm just not seeing. I would appreciate a separate set of eyes and any comments as to what is wrong.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("curl --ntlm -u : --upload-file c:\\temp\\test.xlsx http://site.domain.com/sites/site/SiteDirectory/folder/test.xlsx")
```

Comment: One of the issues was related to the path for Curl.  I supplied the full path for the curl.exe and the errors went away, but it didn't copy the file as it does when I use the exact same command from the command line. I have also passed args with a list with no change in behavior

Comment: Okay, works now.  Was running the script from IDLE IDE, no errors.. but did not work.  Reloaded my script in PythonWin IDE, ran it, worked fine. Sorry for the waste of time. Lesson, don't trust the IDEs.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at second two paragraphs of the [`subprocess.Popen` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) if you haven't already:

> *args* should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in *args* if *args* is a sequence. If *args* is a string, the interpretation is platform-dependent and described below. See the shell and executable arguments for additional differences from the default behavior. Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass *args* as a sequence.
>
> On Unix, if *args* is a string, the string is interpreted as the name or path of the program to execute. **However, this can only be done if not passing arguments to the program.** [emphasis mine]

Instead you should pass in a *list* in which each argument to the program (including the executable name itself) is given as a separate item in the list.  This is generally going to be safer in a cross-platform context anyways.

**Update**: I see now that you're using Windows in which case the advice on UNIX doesn't apply.  On Windows though things are [even more hairy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#converting-argument-sequence).  The best advice remains to use a list :)

**Update 2**: Another possible issue (and in fact the OP's issue as reported in the comments on this answer) is that because the full path to the `curl` executable was not given, it may not be found if the Python interpreter is running in an environment with a different `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Okay, parameterized things and still get the same error.

Comment: commandargs = [
    'curl',
    '--ntlm', ':', 
    '--upload-file',
    srcFile,
    destLib + destFile
]

Comment: It may be that the environment your Python is running in doesn't have the correct PATH set for some reason.  You can try this by printing `os.environ['PATH']`.

Comment: You were right!  It was a path issue. I fully qualified the curl.exe and it worked fine. Thank you!

Comment: well... I don't get the error any more. The curl command still doesn't copy the file for me. weird